# is it possible to add manipulations e.g. mouse event to 3d primitives in drawingsurface in silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

A box of primitives were displayed in drawingsurface in silverlight, beside the way of using controls such like sliders to control the primitive box, is it possible to add some events to the box. for example, it detects if the mouse moves over the box in the drawingsurface.

Comment: I think that won't be straightforward no. You need to look up 3D picking if your view is real 3D.

Comment: my thinking was, if the 3d object was drawn in the drawingsurface - note the 3d object was not an object, then how could it have mouse events?

Comment: You would have to do it all yourself: project from screen space (mouse coordinates) into 3D space, pick object, notify object.